# Usage of "an algorithm was proposed that"

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order, passive-voice

Is it good English to say

> An algorithm was proposed that <does something>.

as opposed to

> An algorithm that <does something> was proposed.

?

Comment: Some people are probably going to object to the passive verb. I kind of think the first one is more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both options proposed by the original poster are grammatically correct.  They sound formal to my (American) ear.  Without any other context, the first option sounds the most natural to me.

Some chronicles (like in the appendices of *The Lord of the Rings*) consist of a table of dates and events.  In such a chronicle, the second option is a natural way to describe an event.  A variation on this option is often used when providing historical background in an essay or in a research paper, such as:

> An algorithm that <does something> was first proposed in <year>.

or

> An algorithm that <does something> was first proposed by <author(s)> in <year>.

If other information is available (like who made the proposal), the active voice is more natural:

> <Author(s)> proposed an algorithm that <does something>.

or

> In <year>, <author(s)> proposed an algorithm that <does something>.